# Why is Shuffle Returning None

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, shuffle

I'm using the random module for a program and don't want items from the list to repeat, so I'm using shuffle. The problem is when I run it, it returns None instead of the items in the list.

```
from random import shuffle

list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

new_list = []

for l in list:
   n = shuffle(list)
   new_list.append(n)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: `shuffle(x)` will *Shuffle list x in place, and return None.*

Answer (score 2):

Shuffle is an in-place operation - i.e. it shuffles the original list. You can change your code to this:

```py
from random import shuffle

list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

new_list = []

for i in range(0, len(list)):
   shuffle(list)
   new_list.append(list)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.shuffle()` does the shuffle in place, @Aziz has a good answer. If you want to get return value then use `.sample()`:

```
from random import sample

Alist = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

new_list = []

for l in Alist:
   n = sample(Alist,k=len(Alist))
   new_list.append(n)
print(new_list)
```